# Question about an Toeic test

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

In Toeic test, Part 1 shows a picture to testers, and they instruct to pick up an appropriate description. A picture shows that a man wears clothes, and several examples described are provided like the following.

> #1. A man is putting on a jacket.
>
> #2. A man is wearing a jacket.

#2 of two is a correct answer. As everyone knows, #1 expresses the ongoing of action. #2 expresses the state of completed action. I don't know the situation is well described though.

As you know, *Be verb + ing* shows that ongoing action is happening, but #2 shows the state in contrast with *the same form*. I want to know the reason for the difference and which verbs there are to the expression of *the state*.

Comment: The difference is because of the meaning of the verbs. As you say, to _put on_ a garment is an action, to _wear_ a garment is to have it on already.

Comment: Toeic?? What's that?

Comment: @Lambie- Test of English for International Communication, apparently.

Comment: wear : to have something on your body as a piece of clothing, a decoration, etc.

Answer (score 2):

#1. A man is putting on **a** jacket.

#2. A man is wearing **a** jacket.

> Verbs are said to be telic or atelic. That means the action has an end
> point or does not.

[telecity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telicity)

When someone puts on a jacket, *the action has an end point*. The verb is telic. You can refer to the point when he or she is putting it on, but, that point won't last for long:

"Hey, Amy, I'm putting  on a jacket and I'll be right there!"

Once the jacket (or any other item of clothing) is put on, the person can keep wearing it for an indefinite period of time. The verb is atelic.

"Look, Amy, today I'm wearing my blue jacket!"

Comment: Thanks! Just difficult for me. The atelic verb example is *she is walking down the street.* The preposition *down* shows the beginning and the ending place, then why is it *(is walking)* the atelic verb without a endpoint?

Comment: @bak1936 walking up or walking down the street does not affect whether the verb is telic or not. walk/down the street//walk//up the street. Those are prepositional phrases and not phrasal verbs.

Comment: In the test, Could you explain me difference between in(within) a hour and for a hour? Even I don't get kind of a little difference between them.

Comment: @bak1936 First, we say: explain the difference to me, and not: explain me the difference. do something within an hour=before the hour (60 minutes) is finished. for an hour= do something for that length of time. :)

Comment: Thanks! I made a mistake, and I haven't know the exact meaning of the *within*. I have been reading the part linked in your post. I need more time. Even I haven't distinguished between exactly action verbs and state verbs. I learn difficulties reading it. Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: @bak1936 I didn't know the exact meaning of x. Don't worry. Take all the time you need.